# Draw data from two tables

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL on Test sites and can not get past this question. (Test Dome)

> Each item in a web shop belongs to a seller. To ensure service quality, each seller has a rating.

The data are kept in the following two tables:

```
TABLE sellers
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  rating INTEGER NOT NULL

TABLE items
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  sellerId INTEGER REFERENCES sellers(id)
```

> Write a query that selects the item name and the name of its seller for each item that belongs to a seller with a rating greater than 4. The query should return the name of the item as the first column and name of the seller as the second column.

I've tried the following which has gotten me closest of my attempts:

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name
FROM sellers, items
WHERE sellers.rating > 4;
```

Thanks in advance for bothering with my noob question.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there but you forgot to specify the join condition, without which would be a `cross join` (all possible combinations of both table rows)

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name
  FROM sellers, items
  WHERE sellers.rating > 4
  AND items.sellerId = sellers.id;
```

In a more extended form the above should be the same as below

```
SELECT items.name, sellers.name
FROM sellers
INNER JOIN items
ON sellers.id = items.id
WHERE sellers.rating > 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the tables.

Here's a link to the tutorial on w3s, this topic is explained quite well here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp